# Flattening a Scala Map in an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an an RDD that looks like:

```
uidProcessedKeywords: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, Map[String,Double])]
```

How do I flatten the map in the RDD to get this:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, String, Double)]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
val x = sc.parallelize(List((2, Map("a" -> 0.2, "b" -> 0.3))))
x.flatMap { 
    case (id, m) => m.map { case (k, v) => (id, k, v)}
  }
 .collect()
res1: Array[(Int, String, Double)] = Array((2,a,0.2), (2,b,0.3))
```